# Hibernate one-to-many collection deleted

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an Object holding 3 Collections. The Objects in these Collections inherite form the same Superclass.

I use SingleTable Inheritance with @ForceDiscriminator.

The Collections are unidirectional One-To-Many.

When I clear one of these Collections the other two loose their foreign key link to the holding object.

I use Hibernate 3.5.3 in an WebSphere 7 (with a JPA2.0 feature pack) Container.

**Entities**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name="PLANUNG")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="DISC", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("dummy")
@ForceDiscriminator
public abstract class Planung extends EntityBase {

@Column(name = "JAHR", nullable=false)
private int jahr;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="PLANUNG_ID", referencedColumnName="id")
@OrderBy("id ASC") 
private List<Werte> Werte;

[...]

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(PlanungA.NAME)
public class PlanungA extends Planung {
    public static final String NAME = "PlanungA";
}
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(PlanungB.NAME)
public class PlanungB extends Planung {
    public static final String NAME = "PlanungB";
}
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(PlanungC.NAME)
public class PlanungC extends Planung {
    public static final String NAME = "PlanungC";
}


---

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(Base.NAME)
public class Base extends AbstractBase {
public static final String NAME = "Base";

@OrderBy("jahr ASC")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name="BASE_ID", referencedColumnName="id")
private List<PlanungA> planungA;

@OrderBy("jahr ASC")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name="BASE_ID", referencedColumnName="id")
private List<PlanungB> planungB;

@OrderBy("jahr ASC")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name="BASE_ID", referencedColumnName="id")
private List<PlanungC> planungC;

[...]
```

**Application Code**

```
List list = base.getPlanungA();
list.clear();
```

**Problem**

Beside other statements Hibernate issues this SQL:

```
update
    PLANUNG 
set
    BASE_ID=null 
where
    BASE_ID=?
```

As a consequence all Collections (PlanungA, B, C) loose their reference to the Base object.

A Discriminator is missing (eg. AND DISC='PlanungA').

**What I already tried**

- I already upgraded to Hibernate 3.6.10.Final (just to try). It did not solve this behaviour.
- Searched the world ...

Any help, pointing me to similar issues etc. is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be a Hibernate bug : https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1134

Comment: Problem solved! As I dont have 10 reputation I can't answer to my own question within 8h.
I will post the solution tomorrow.

Comment: You used a different column for each foreign key ? That was the first idea that came to my mind but that's more a hack than a solution ...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, overmeulen, for pointing me to the corresponding [hibernate issue](http://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1134). It is still an open Hibernate bug.

I applied one of the solutions mentioned in the issue comments:

```
@OrderBy("jahr ASC")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name="BASE_ID", referencedColumnName="id")
@Where(clause="DISC='PlanungA'")
private List<PlanungA> planungA;
```

By inserting **@Where** the statement is issued by the OR Mapping as follows:

```
update
    PLANUNG 
set
    BASE_ID=null 
where
    BASE_ID=? 
    and (
        DISC='PlanungA'
    )
```

Problem solved

Thanks!